# GC overhead limit exceeded for assets:precompile in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, passenger, apache2.4

When I run `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` , I got the below error

```
Java::JavaLang::OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
(in   /home/avijit/railswork/tracksynqv2/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
 org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(org/mozilla/javascript/Interpreter.java:1382)
 org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(org/mozilla/javascript/Interpreter.java:815)
 org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(org/mozilla/javascript/InterpretedFunction.java:109)
 org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(org/mozilla/javascript/ContextFactory.java:393)
 org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(org/mozilla/javascript/ScriptRuntime.java:3280)
 org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(org/mozilla/javascript/InterpretedFunction.java:107)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java/lang/reflect/Method.java:498)
 RUBY.call(/home/avijit/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.16/gems/therubyrhino-2.0.4/lib/rhino/rhino_ext.rb:193)
 Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I update my production.rb file with config.assets.compile = true and config.serve_static_assets = true. I deploy my rails app using passenger and apache2.

Comment: How much memory do you have in it?

Answer (score 0):

assets:precompile comsume a lot of memory when you run it; try check you system monitor when you running it and increase you memory in the server where you execute that task.

By the way config.serve_static_assets = false should be false in production the server software (e.g. NGINX or Apache) used to run the application should serve static assets instead. Also now this property was rename to config.serve_static_files, as I remember.